# Python function that creates map with cells

Tags: python

I want to create a square map that contains cells with a function. Function should take one variable that represents range of the map (range of 3 means that map is 3x3 = 9 cells and so on). Each cell should have coordinates that looks like this:
A1,A2,A3...B1,B2,B3...C1,C2,C3... and so on. Ofc, maximum range should be 26 (26x26). 
I want to append those cells in the in the list. 
I wrote a code that does that but only with numbers, I do not now how to create coordinates with letters.
This is the code:

```
def mapCells(n):

    cell_List = []

    for x in range (1,n+1):
        for y in range (1, n+1):

            cell = str(x) + str(y)

            cell_List.append(cell)

    print(cell_List)

mapCells(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace str(x) code with chr(64 + x)

Comment: ok,is there any other, way or this is the only one? And also, maximum range should be 26x26. What code should write so that i can prevent user to enter number greater then 26?

Comment: You can check argument n if it is greater than 26, you can raise Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) to get the letters and use a slice of length `n` for your coordinates:

```
import string

def mapCells(n):
    cell_List = []
    for x in string.ascii_uppercase[:n]:
        for y in range(1, min(n + 1, 27)):
            cell = x + str(y)
            cell_List.append(cell)
    print(cell_List)

mapCells(3)
```

**Output**

```
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3']
```